# Buscar un array por uno de sus valores dentro de otro array en PHP

Tags: php, array

Tengo un **array en PHP** con una estructura similar a la siguiente (obtenido usando el `fech_all()` para obtener todas las filas de una tabla):

#### var_dump() de $miarray

```
array(3) {
    [0]=> array(3) {
        [0]=> string(1) "1" // option_id
        [1]=> string(9) "site_name" // option_name
        [2]=> string(8) "FullAuth" // option_value
    }
    [1]=> array(3) {
        [0]=> string(1) "2" // option_id
        [1]=> string(8) "home_url" // option_name
        [2]=> string(25) "http://ejemplo.com" // option_value
    }
    [2]=> array(3) {
        [0]=> string(1) "3" // option_id
        [1]=> string(8) "auth_url" // option_name
        [2]=> string(31) "http://ejemplo.com/user/" // option_value
    }
}
```

Para que se me entienda mejor, cada uno de esos subarrays son una opción almacenada en una base de datos y lo que quiero conseguir es **acceder al valor (option_value) de cada una de las opciones tan solo conociendo su nombre** (option_name).

#### Me gustaría conseguir algo así:

```
function obtenerOpcion($option_name) {
    // Buscar la opción dentro de $miarray
    // return...
}

echo obtenerOpcion("home_url"); // http://ejemplo.com
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si he entendido bien, dado un valor como `home_url` u otro, quieres obtener el valor que sigue, en este caso: `http://ejemplo.com`

En base al array que tienes, puedes programar una función como esta:

```
function getOption ($arraySuperior,$mValue){
    foreach ($arraySuperior as $subArray){
        foreach ($subArray as $k=>$v){
            if ($v==$mValue){
                /*
                    Encontrado el valor, no seguimos iterando sobre el array
                    retornando el dato que se encuentre en la clave 
                    siguiente a donde se encuentre a $mValue
                */
                return $subArray[$k+1];
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

---

Probemos la función con varias posibilidades:

```
$mOption=getOption($arraySuperior,"home_url");
var_dump($mOption);   //string(18) "http://ejemplo.com"
```

---

```
$mOption=getOption($arraySuperior,"site_name");
var_dump($mOption);  //string(8) "FullAuth"
```

---

```
$mOption=getOption($arraySuperior,"fake");
var_dump($mOption);  //NULL
```

---

### Recomendación

Dado que `fetch_all` acepta un parámetro para crear arreglos asociativos, sería mejor que crees un array de ese tipo, así podrás acceder al valor de una forma más certera usando el nombre de la columna.

En la respuesta dada se asume que no hay irregularidades en el array (siempre `option_value` estará después de `option_name`), si no fuera así, no se obtendría el valor correcto, por eso es siempre más seguro obtener los valores por el nombre del índice y no por el número secuencial.

Si se pasara a `fetch_all` la bandera para arreglo asociativo, el mismo se crearía así:

```
$arraySuperior= array(
             array(
                        "option_id" => "1", 
                        "option_name" => "site_name",
                        "option_value" => "FullAuth"
            ),
             array(
                        "option_id" => "2",
                        "option_value" => "http://ejemplo.com",
                        "option_name" => "home_url",
            ),
            array(
                        "option_id" => "3",
                        "option_name" => "auth_url",
                        "option_value" => "http://ejemplo.com/user/"
            )
);
```

NÓTESE que de forma intencional he puesto un orden distinto en el segundo array.

No habría problema, porque la función va a buscar el valor por el nombre de la clave, sin importar que esté después o antes de `option_name`:

```
function getOption ($arraySuperior,$mValue){
    foreach ($arraySuperior as $subArray){
        foreach ($subArray as $k=>$v){
            if ($v==$mValue){
                /*
                    Encontrado el valor, no seguimos iterando sobre el array
                    retornando el dato que se encuentre en la clave 
                    siguiente a donde se encuentre a $mValue
                */
                return $subArray["option_value"];
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Además, esto haría el código **más portable**. Supongamos que se quiere buscar no solamente el `option_value`, sino que en algunos casos se requiere el `option_id`. La misma función serviría, agregando un tercer parámetro y una verificación suplementaria sobre `$mKey`:

```
function getOption ($arraySuperior,$mValue,$mKey){
    foreach ($arraySuperior as $subArray){
        foreach ($subArray as $k=>$v){
            if ( $v==$mValue && isset($subArray[$mKey]) ){
                /*
                    Encontrado el valor, no seguimos iterando sobre el array
                    retornando el dato que se encuentre en la clave 
                    siguiente a donde se encuentre a $mValue
                */
                return $subArray[$mKey];
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

**Pruebas varias:**

```
$mOption=getOption($arraySuperior,"home_url","option_value");
var_dump($mOption);   //string(18) "http://ejemplo.com"

$mOption=getOption($arraySuperior,"home_url","option_id");
var_dump($mOption);   //string(1) "2"

$mOption=getOption($arraySuperior,"home_url","option_ids");
var_dump($mOption);   //NULL

$mOption=getOption($arraySuperior,"fake","option_id");
var_dump($mOption);   //NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Partiendo de un array en **PHP** similar al propuesto:

```php
//Array propuesto
$arraySuperior= array(
            0 => array(
                        0 => "1", // option_id
                        1 => "site_name", // option_name
                        2 => "FullAuth"// option_value
            ),
            1 => array(
                        0 => "2", // option_id
                        1 => "home_url", // option_name
                        2 => "http://ejemplo.com" // option_value
            ),
            2=> array(
                        0 => "3", // option_id
                        1 => "auth_url", // option_name
                        2 => "http://ejemplo.com/user/"// option_value
            )

);
```

Creas una funcion, la cual tiene que recibir **dos argumentos**, un argumento para la busqueda y otro argumento que debe ser el array donde se debe efectuar la busqueda. Puedes realizar algo similar a lo siguiente:

```php
//Funcion
function obtenerOpcion($option_name, $arrayBusqueda){
    foreach($arrayBusqueda as $keyInt=>$arrayInterno){
            foreach($arrayInterno as $keyInte=>$valor){
                    if($valor==$option_name){
                            $mode=current($arrayInterno);
                            $mode=next($arrayInterno);
                            $mode=next($arrayInterno);
                            return $mode;
                    }
           }
    }
}
```

El resultado del `echo` será el deseado:

```php
echo obtenerOpcion("home_url",$arraySuperior);// http://ejemplo.com
```

También puedes crear una función que reciba **solo el argumento deseado** de la siguiente manera:

```php
//Funcion
function obtenerOpcion($option_name){
    foreach($GLOBALS['arraySuperior'] as $keyInt=>$arrayInterno){
            foreach($arrayInterno as $keyInte=>$valor){
                    if($valor==$option_name){
                            $mode=current($arrayInterno);
                            $mode=next($arrayInterno);
                            $mode=next($arrayInterno);
                            return $mode;
                    }
            }
    }
}

//Resultado
echo obtenerOpcion("home_url");// http://ejemplo.com
```

Answer (score 1):

En un arreglo de dos dimensiones se necesitan dos índices para seleccionar un elemento.

1. Primer índice: array_search($option_name, array_column($arraySuperior,1))
2. Segundo índice: 2

[`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-column.php) genera el arreglo ["site_name","home_url","auth_url]
[`array_search`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-search.php) busca la posición de option_name en dicho arreglo

```
function obtenerOpcion($option_name) {
    global $arraySuperior;
    return $arraySuperior[array_search($option_name, array_column($arraySuperior,1))][2];
}
```